# How do I "unroot" my android device

Tags: root-access

Now with Pokemon GO pushing the new update and not allowing rooted devices in the game, I want to reverse that.

So how do I unroot my device

**Bonus**: How do I manipulate the app into thinking I do not have root access

**Edit**: I used SuperUser's Full unroot option but it does not remove root access. Either SuperUser has a problem or my phone's jacked up

Comment: If this is the case, it explains a large amount of the lost users ;) (including me, cry!).

Comment: Sorry, but your question is off topic here. The [android] tag gives specific guidance for this. I have voted to migrate to the proper site.

Comment: But Which site?

Comment: Look I'm in mobile, I'm sorry

Answer (score 1):

If you want to unroot only to play Pokemon Go, you don't need to do so.

Just root with Magisk:

- Download the magisk installer from [the official post on XDA-Developers](https://forum.xda-developers.com/apps/magisk/official-magisk-v7-universal-systemless-t3473445)
- Flash it with the custom recovery.
- Install the Magisk app (also in that post on XDA)

Now, to hide root from Pokemon GO:

- Go to Magisk Hide and enable Pokemon GO
- Go to Settings, and press on Hide Magisk Manager

It will take a while, just let it work. 
When it finishes, reboot your device and open Pokemon Go.
If it still detects root, clear the data of Pokemon Go.

Answer (score 0):

**How to Unroot**

1. Open SuperSU and go to the settings tab.
2. Scroll down and press "Full unroot".
3. You'll be asked to confirm you want to fully unroot, press continue.
4. SuperSU will close when finished, now restart your device.
5. Now uninstall SuperSU and you should be unrooted.

   **Make Pokemon GO think you're unrooted**
   An application called Magisk can do this. I have not tried it, but you're meant to be able to "turn off" root when playing Pokemon GO, and back on again when you're not. This will also work for Android Pay because it also uses the same method to detect root.
   I would probably try this one:
   [Magisk! – How to Play Pokemon Go on Rooted Android!](http://highonandroid.com/android-apps/magisk-how-to-play-pokemon-go-on-rooted-android/)

Or you can search online for other tutorials on how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to unroot. You can use Magisk to hide your root status. Head over to XDA to learn how to do it.

Answer (score -2):

### First How to Just Unroot the Device

You can unroot the phone by opening SuperSU app and choosing full unroot (or just removing /system/bin/su is sufficient usually, and can be done with a file manager like ES File Manager (left hand tray has tools header and under that is the root access toggle and Mount R/W tap that and select /system to be rw) you can then delete the su binary in /system/bin (sometimes /system/xbin though this is more rare)).

### More Detail and possible solutions [First Guest Account]

I do not know of any direct ways of hiding SU from apps, but you could try a guest user and if you leave the multi user option in SuperSU unchecked then the guest user account may be able to run the app and the app may not see the root.

### More Detail and possible solutions [Second Unroot then use Custom Recovery to Apply Root when Done]

You can lose root and be OK if you maintain the custom recovery.  Then what you could do is do full unroot from inside SuperSU app and restart device. Now install and/or run Pokemon GO!.  When done restart to recovery and flash SuperSU.zip and restart again.  Now you will have root access back until next time you wish to play Pokemon GO!.

### Editorial [some Concern for Users from the Author]

Now you do realize Pokemon GO! was done by an NSA contracted company and is used by the government as a general spy tool (think about it a bunch of people running anround with phone cameras and mics running is a wet dream for those guys), so you may want to re-think what games you play and what permissions you are allowing apps running on your devices to use (same guy that designed Google Earth Originally for the CIA/NSA before Google Bought it and same guy who wrote the Game Ingress that was originally done by a company under direct CIA contract before Google bought them).

Reference [I'm not just a conspiracy theory nut without backup proof ;-)]: 
https://www.corbettreport.com/the-cias-pokemon-go-app-is-doing-what-the-patriot-act-cant/
http://www.networkworld.com/article/3099092/mobile-wireless/the-cia-nsa-and-pokmon-go.html

Comment: I'm not really sure your conspiracy theory has anything to do with answering the OP's question.

Comment: as the newly added header suggests it's just concern from me to users, plus also demonstrates why it is a good idea to investigate permissions users grant to applications they use which does have practical security applications.

Comment: Great but again, not relevant to the question...

Comment: Relevant in that security should be thought of in everything you do not just a subject spoken about when directly queried.  The example given is for the OPs directly stated app its not just something added out of left field.

Comment: I appreciate your feedback on this and for me that kinda thing is more an exception than the rule as evidenced by my others answers around the site.  The example given is just soo blatant I would have felt like I let users of that app down if I did not at least mention it.

Comment: Okay that's great and all, but still, the conspiracy theory adds nothing to your answer, and in fact was unwarranted completely, the OP never asked about the mechanics behind Pokemon GO...

Comment: It adds information pertaining to the app the user is using and could help them decide whether or not the proposed solutions are worth the trouble or if since they may not have known of this may cause them to not use the app and not need to go through the motions of the answer and is a third option if you will.  Yes it is a slight stretch, but again I feel it does add some valuable info (as reference links show this is not just my opinion research has been done).